# Format paragraph like MS Word

Tags: html, css

I want to format a paragraph to be like MS Word (attached image)
[image]

This is what I've done so far:

```css
ol {
  text-align: justify;
}

ol.first {
  list-style: upper-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol.second {
  list-style: upper-latin;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol.third {
  list-style: lower-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}

ol li .number {
  display: list-item;
}

ol li .content {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="first">
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ipsum nisi, hendrerit vel tristique vel, ornare eget ligula. Quisque ipsum eros, rhoncus nec luctus et, interdum quis est. Quisque semper id magna sed iaculis. Vestibulum ornare aliquam
      neque nec consectetur. Curabitur molestie venenatis urna sed congue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol class="second">
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

https://codepen.io/BraveVN1804/pen/NvxYyJ

But the paragraphs are not aligned on the same vertical line when the Roman numberings increased. I can fix it by refactoring code using `table`, but in my situation it's not a good idea so I want to do it with `list`.

Comment: Something like this? http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/99285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/prowseed/f5a3p8qd/

Basically all you have to do is to remove natural counter and instead use css `counter()` features inside `:before` pseudo element that is positioned absolutely inside relative `li` parent.

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ol>



ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}

ol li {
  position:relative;
  padding:10px 0 10px 80px;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(mycounter, upper-roman);
    counter-increment: mycounter;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set fixed width to your `.number`. Demo:

```css
ol {
  text-align: justify;
}

ol.first {
  list-style: upper-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol.second {
  list-style: upper-latin;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol.third {
  list-style: lower-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}

ol li .number {
  width: 50px; /* new */
  display: list-item;
}

ol li .content {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="first">
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ipsum nisi, hendrerit vel tristique vel, ornare eget ligula. Quisque ipsum eros, rhoncus nec luctus et, interdum quis est. Quisque semper id magna sed iaculis. Vestibulum ornare aliquam
      neque nec consectetur. Curabitur molestie venenatis urna sed congue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol class="second">
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="number"></div>
        <div class="content">Labore exercitation fugiat mollit nostrud. Dolore quis id aliquip eu reprehenderit proident. Cupidatat ullamco esse non nisi minim et veniam sunt labore proident esse ea ex. Officia sint deserunt cupidatat amet irure esse fugiat laborum. Aliqua
          deserunt aute cillum enim officia irure ut officia proident ea. Quis sunt enim esse reprehenderit aute est.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number"></div>
    <div class="content">Phasellus vel convallis magna. Nam ex quam, lacinia ac facilisis et, tempor vitae elit. Duis sit amet urna scelerisque, molestie ipsum sed, ultricies orci. Duis ac purus congue, maximus enim ut, rutrum quam. Quisque porta bibendum ex, eget laoreet
      neque eleifend eu. Etiam ac leo a dui consectetur dictum ut in lacus.</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```